# Custom Hashmap Stops working after few insertion

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code for a custom hashmap (array of linked lists) which can store 500 millions of values (keys are linked list array number) and can save the index to the disk. The code is following:

Comment: What do you mean by "stop working"?

Comment: Do you get an error message of some kind?

Comment: Do you call 210 million "a few"?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, no it's just blocked. Means upto 210 million, it inserts in 3 seconds. But after that I just wait for 2 minutes, code just blocked.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen,no it's just blocked. Means upto 210 million, it inserts in 3 seconds. But after that I just wait for 2 minutes, code just blocked.

Comment: Does your server really have 20GB? Did you turn on GC logging?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, My server has 32 GB. I give 20 gb by Xms & Xmx.

Comment: You don't need the BitSet if you check for `l[key] != null` instead. Instead of using a linked list of Nodes, using a single `int[]` may be more efficient.

Comment: Do you have 20Gb of *disk* to save to ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew, why 20 GB disk is required ? BTW, 128 GB disk.

Comment: I was just concerned that your save() is blocked. If you have sufficient disk, then all well and good on that front

Comment: For 500 million keys you need that many nodes plus the array is about 16 GB.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I have given it 20GB.

Comment: For disk space you need 4 bytes per values and 4 bytes per key to write out the `-1`s

Comment: @PeterLawrey I do not need to save keys as they are from 0 to Int_Max.

Comment: You are saving when the last value is written. There is one for these for each possible key.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I am just saving those values, which has only filled up linked lists by using bitset. So, (number of values * 4 bytes) + (4 bytes for -1 * number of linked list filled) number of bytes required.

Comment: That is true.  When you read the file can you assume that all the keys from 0 to n are filled because you won't know which key the next values are for when you load them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would implement it

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Arrays;

class LongIntParallelHashMultimap {
    public static final int BUFFER_BITS = 24;
    private final FileChannel fc;
    private final ByteBuffer[] keys, data;
    private final int topBits, topMask, offsetMask;

    public LongIntParallelHashMultimap(String fileName, int sizeBits, boolean load) throws IOException {
        fc = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw").getChannel();
        long totalSize = 4L << sizeBits;
        int bufferIndex = (int) (totalSize >> BUFFER_BITS);
        keys = new ByteBuffer[bufferIndex];
        data = new ByteBuffer[bufferIndex];
        int bufferSize = 1 << BUFFER_BITS;
        long offset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferIndex; i++) {
            MappedByteBuffer kmap = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, offset, bufferSize);
            kmap.load();
            keys[i] = kmap.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            MappedByteBuffer dmap = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, offset + bufferSize, bufferSize);
            dmap.load();
            data[i] = dmap.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            offset += bufferSize * 2;
        }
        topBits = sizeBits + 2 - BUFFER_BITS;
        topMask = (1 << topBits) - 1;
        offsetMask = bufferSize - 4;
    }

    public void put(int key, int value) {
        int buffer = key & topMask;
        int key2 = (key >> topBits) + 1;
        assert key2 != 0;
        ByteBuffer keys2 = keys[buffer];
        ByteBuffer data2 = data[buffer];
        int offset = (key2 * 101) & offsetMask;
        while (keys2.getInt(offset) != 0) {
            offset += 3 * 4;
            offset &= offsetMask;
        }
        keys2.putInt(offset, key2);
        data2.putInt(offset, value);
    }

    public int get(int key, int[] values) {
        int buffer = key & topMask;
        int key2 = (key >> topBits) + 1;
        assert key2 != 0;
        ByteBuffer keys2 = keys[buffer];
        ByteBuffer data2 = data[buffer];
        int offset = (key2 * 101) & offsetMask;
        for (int count = 0; count < values.length; ) {
            int key3 = keys2.getInt(offset);
            if (key3 == 0)
                return count;
            if (key3 == key2)
                values[count++] = data2.getInt(offset);

            offset += 3 * 4;
            offset &= offsetMask;
        }
        return values.length;
    }

    private final int[] getValues = new int[1000];
    private static final int[] NO_VALUES = { };

    public int[] get(int key) {
        int len = get(key, getValues);
        return len == 0 ? NO_VALUES : Arrays.copyOf(getValues, len);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        int keys = 500 * 1000 * 1000;

        new File("abc.bin").delete();
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        LongIntParallelHashMultimap lph = new LongIntParallelHashMultimap("abc.bin", 30, true);
        long time = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.printf("Load time was %.3f sec%n", time / 1e9);

        timePut(keys, lph);

        timeGet(keys, lph);

        timeGet2(keys, lph);

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.gc();
        time = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.printf("Time to Full GC was %.3f sec%n", time / 1e9);
    }

    private static void timePut(int keys, LongIntParallelHashMultimap lph) {
        long startTime;
        long time;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
            lph.put(i, i + 100);
            if ((i + 1) % 100_000_000 == 0)
                System.out.printf("%,d ", i + 1);
        }
        time = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.printf("%nput time was %.3f sec%n", time / 1e9);
    }

    private static void timeGet(int keys, LongIntParallelHashMultimap lph) {
        long startTime;
        long time;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int[] values = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
            lph.get(i, values);
            if ((i + 1) % 100_000_000 == 0)
                System.out.printf("%,d ", i + 1);
        }
        time = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.printf("%nget(key, values) time was %.3f sec%n", time / 1e9);
    }

    private static void timeGet2(int keys, LongIntParallelHashMultimap lph) {
        long startTime;
        long time;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
            lph.get(i);
            if ((i + 1) % 100_000_000 == 0)
                System.out.printf("%,d ", i + 1);
        }
        time = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.printf("%nget(key) time was %.3f sec%n", time / 1e9);
    }
}
```

Note: there is no additional step to load or save the data.  This means when you return from `put(key, value)` the data is saved even if you program crashes (assuming your OS doesn't crash)

This adds 500m entries. run with `-ea -verbosegc -mx16m` That's a maximum heap of 16 MB.

```
Load time was 0.121 sec
100,000,000 200,000,000 300,000,000 400,000,000 500,000,000 
put time was 47.017 sec
100,000,000 200,000,000 300,000,000 400,000,000 500,000,000 
get(key, values) time was 50.858 sec
[ GC goes bananas for get(key) ]
100,000,000 200,000,000 300,000,000 400,000,000 500,000,000 
get(key) time was 87.634 sec
Time to Full GC was 0.015 sec
```

Note: it only GCed because I called `System.gc();` and look at the size of the heap used!

---

I would use a `int[]` instead of a linked list of nodes.

```
import sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

class LongIntParallelHashMultimap {
    private static final int[] NO_INTS = {};

    final int[][] data;

    public LongIntParallelHashMultimap() {
        data = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE][];
    }

    public void put(int key, int value) {
        int[] ints = data[key];
        if (ints == null) {
            data[key] = new int[]{value};
        } else {
            int[] ints2 = Arrays.copyOf(ints, ints.length + 1);
            ints2[ints.length] = value;
            data[key] = ints2;
        }
    }

    public int[] get(int key) {
        int[] ints = data[key];
        return ints == null ? NO_INTS : ints;
    }

    private FileChannel channel;
    private MappedByteBuffer mbb;

    public void save() throws IOException {
        channel = new RandomAccessFile("abc.bin", "rw").getChannel();
        mbb = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 1 << 24);
        mbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE - 32; i += 32) {
            int bits = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
                if (data[i + j] != null) bits |= 1;
                bits <<= 1;
            }
            getMbb().putInt(bits);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            int arr[] = get(i);
            if (arr.length == 0) continue;
            getMbb().putInt(arr.length);
            for (int a : arr)
                getMbb().putInt(a);
        }
        channel.close();
        cleanMbb();
    }

    private ByteBuffer getMbb() throws IOException {
        if (mbb.remaining() <= 0) {
            cleanMbb();
            mbb = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, channel.size(), 1 << 24);
            mbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        }
        return mbb;
    }

    private void cleanMbb() {
        ((DirectBuffer) mbb).cleaner().clean();
    }


    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        int keys = 50 * 1000 * 1000;

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        LongIntParallelHashMultimap lph = new LongIntParallelHashMultimap();
        long time = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.printf("Create time %.3f sec%n", time / 1e9);

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
            lph.put(i, i + 100);
            if (i % 10000000 == 0 && i != 0)
                System.out.print(" " + i + " ");
        }
        time = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.printf("%nput time was %.3f sec%n", time / 1e9);

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        lph.save();
        time = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.printf(" time to save was %.3f sec%n", time / 1e9);

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
            int k[] = lph.get(i);
        }
        time = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.printf("get time was %.3f sec%n", time / 1e9);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code is really nice. But, one point, I think, disk space can be saved more (and so disk IO also) if a bitset is used to check which int[] are filled. Because, in your save approach, you have to save (number of values * 4 bytes) + (4 bytes * Int_Max). What you think about it ?

Comment: You could write out a bitset from the array first.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really what I am looking for. But, how to reverse calculate the bitset (I mean bits). I mean while loading.

Comment: Read the `int` values into an array and use this to determine which values to read later. The bit set doesn't need to be retained.

Comment: I try to mean how "for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
                if (data[i + j] != null) bits |= 1;
                bits <<= 1;
            }" has to reverse calculate in order to find which values I have to put.

Comment: Another point, is there any procedure to put whole array of values to it's corresponding position. Actually, I want to avoid else part of this code  public void put(int key, int value) {
        int[] ints = data[key];
        if (ints == null) {
            data[key] = new int[]{value};
        } else {
            int[] ints2 = Arrays.copyOf(ints, ints.length + 1);
            ints2[ints.length] = value;
            data[key] = ints2;
        }
    }

Comment: I can't think of a simpler or more efficient way of doing that.

Comment: What I have done in the past is place the entire data structure only in the memory mapped file. This means load and save take almost no time and there is far less chance of data loss. It also means it uses very little heap (<< 100KB)

Comment: Peter, can you kindly illustrate what I should have to do by modifying your code (means by adding load procedure).

Comment: I have modified my OP with current code. Can you kindly take a look on it and advice me if it is nice or not. Specially the load and save method. Code can be found also here. https://gist.github.com/3249980

Comment: I have modified the code to the way I would do it.  I hope you can see it much faster and has almost no use of the heap.  While it uses more disk space, disk space is much cheaper than memory.

Comment: But, I want [] value = get(key) method. How to modify the above code thus I can get that. Another point, I have to load it next day (not at that moment actually, means OS just lost data) is that remain faster for that also.

Comment: You can do that, it will just be slower.

Comment: How to do that (say in this https://gist.github.com/3249980)? And why sizebits are set to 30 ? And  as I have to load it next day (not at that moment actually, means OS will just lost data) is that remain faster for that also. The code is really hard to get. I have to spent more time to get it. If possible, please give me some little pointer to get it.

Comment: I have added an example for `get(key)` and a test suggesting its ~70% slower due to the need to create a `int[]`. The sizebit is 30 as 2**30 > 500m, if you made it 28, your program would fail. If you are loading from disk, you are at the mercy of the speed you can load from disk. I have added calls to `load()` so you can be sure its loaded when the constructor returns.

Comment: In terms of "getting it", I am open for questions because it hard for me to know what you don't. ;)

Comment: OK. Let me check it, I will ask then.

Comment: Peter, in my server https://gist.github.com/3249980 this code (just little bit modifcation with our need and javac) it takes lots of time for put method (I ran it for 5 mins) can you kindly check in in your pc whether I made anything wrong in the above code or not.

Comment: Running your code I get `put time was 46.801 sec` I have an i7 3.6 GHz with Windows 7 Home Edition and an SSD which today costs £74.

Comment: In our server it's SATA. Is that can degrade that much ?

Comment: The SSD is SATA as well. It does 200 MB/s with a seek time of 0.025 ms. A good SSD SATA can do 500 MB/s with a "seek time" of 0.012 ms. A top PCI SSD can do 1,500 MB/s with a "seek time" of 0.004 ms. By comparison a SATA HDD might do 40 MB/s with a seek time of 7 ms.

Comment: Put another way, an SSD can do 40,000 to 230,00 K IOPS (IO operations per second) A typical HDD does 120 IOPS.

Comment: But, in my Server I don't think they will make any change. However, can you kindly check this one (https://gist.github.com/3250916) please. I have added an load method with addition to your previous approach. Can you suggest me is there any issue or not. Actually, we want to reduce disk IO as much as possible. Because disk is really our overhead.

Comment: I don't see any thing wrong, but then again I am very tired. Saw few women's indoor volleyball matches live this week, up past  midnight. ;)

Comment: Just for moment, channel = new RandomAccessFile("abc.dat", "rw").getChannel();
        mbb = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 1 << 24);  // ????? what if >  1 << 24
        mbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        int l = 0 ;
        for(int r = 0 ; r < bs.length(); r++){
         if(bs.get(r)){
         l = mbb.getInt();
         int [] val = new int[l];
         for(int p = 0 ; p < l ; p++)          // put the whole array to 2nd dimention according to bitset
          val[p] = mbb.getInt();
         puts(r , val);

         }
        } section is ok ?

Comment: It is sad when you spent alot of your time trying to optimize your code when they won't spend $100 which would make your program take 50 seconds instead of 5 minutes. (A problem I have found everywhere ;)

Comment: OK. then I ask you later. If I face some issues. BTW, really really thanks.

Comment: BTW As I have often faced an issue where if only they spent a little bit of money it would make your job 10x easier. I often have a better system at home than I have at work because I paid for it myself. Something which works well in this situation is to offer to pay the upgrade with your own money (since they clearly don't have the budget).  This can either a) embarrass them into improving the system b) make the point you really believe this needs to be done.

Comment: The SSD I have a just a cheap one.  Imagine what you could do with something like this which is about 4.5x faster. http://www.ocztechnology.com/ocz-revodrive-hybrid-pci-express-solid-state-drive.html costs < £300.

Comment: I have edited my OP. There is some issue with load method. It just does not wotk after (Int.Max_Value/4) number of ints. can you kindly help me how to handle this kind of situation with File Channel Map.

Comment: Map in the data progressively in blocks of say 16 MB as I do in the second example.

Comment: I haved tried that and code is given in my OP. Gives error java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
        at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:497)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.getInt(DirectByteBuffer.java:639)
 at line number between * in OP.

Comment: You are not using `getMbb().getInt()`

Comment: Today I talked with my manager and he says it's impossible to add such SSD even I buy it because for it they need to change server configuration and need more than 300 GB hard disk which is simply impossible for me.

Comment: However, they gave me a c++ code and run it (given my OP) which takes just 15 seconds to read approx 10 gb file (the code they use previously). Can you kindly check it and inform me why is this happening with us. Because Java is able to read 2 gb file with in 10 seconds while c++ above code ias able to read 9 gb.

Comment: What is the C++ code doing differently? If its taking 15 seconds to read 10 GB are you saying your disks can support 682 MB per second when SATA can only support up to 600 MB/second. I suspect you are not doing a like-for-like test. The Java program can load more data than that when its already loaded into memory.

Comment: In my example the load was 0.121 seconds when the data was already in memory, why is the C++ so much slower?

Comment: But that C++ code gives in my computer which is SATA HDD. Do you mean it has already uploaded the data in memory that's why it is faster ?

Comment: So you can see for yourself that most, if not all the data is in memory to achieve that speed.

Comment: But, we have 32 gb main memory and we have 28 files (14 of values - each of 0.75 gb and 14 of keys -each of 1.50 gb) = 31.5 GB. so it is impossible to keep all of them on memory. When we are using Memory Mapped Buffer for some key value files it takes just 5 seconds while for some 20 seconds. This is because of data is already in main memory. I take it by pre read data. However, from that I get maximum 3 files that can take less time by pre read. Is it possible to make sure that they will keep maximum say for 20/24 gb data in memory. Because rest of the code just takes < 1 gb space.

Comment: Another point, from your suggestion I read each page (actually also for much less than a page) by using memory mapped buffer which just executes in fraction of seconds. But, trully I have not found any performence gain while loading. I just pre-read each page and then perform loading.

Comment: Only the data you force into memory will be loaded. This way you can choice what you want to be pre-loaded or not. Any memory you don't `load()` or access may or may not be in memory.  In the 10 GB example all of it can be in memory for 32 GB machine.